# Django url patterns: good practice?

Tags: django

I am wondering whether the following is considered "bad practice". I have multiple `urls.py` files per app in a Django project. So for example I have in a single app called `locations` I may the following files:

```
# locations/urls/api.py
# locations/urls/general.py
```

Both of these are included in "main url file":

```
# settings/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # ... snip ...
    path('api/locations', include('locations.urls.api')),
    path('locations/', include('locations.urls.general')),
    # ... snip ...
]
```

The reason I am considering this construction is because I want some "location urls" to be within the `api/...` routes combined with routes coming from other apps into the `api/...` routes and some I would like to be just within the `locations/...` routes.

I hope my explaination is clear. Let me know what you think of this construction!

Cheers!

Comment: You are keeping things modular it is good. But I think you can keep urls seperate for apps in `urls.py` only in my opinion and you may consider better naming `api_urls.py` instead of `api.py` as `api.py` sounds where api code resides not urls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually need them to be in separate files. `include` can include a list of patterns: so you could do:

```
api_urlpatterns = [
    path(...),
    path(...),
]
general_urlpatterns = [
    path(...),
    path(...),
]

urlpatterns = [
    # ... snip ...
    path('api/locations', include(api_urlpatterns)),
    path('locations/', include(general_urlpatterns)),
    # ... snip ...
]
```

Comment: Oh snap, this indeed seems better. No idea why I haven't thought about this before. Thanks!